# How to paintComponent to display objects in Java?

Tags: java, graphics, jpanel, paint

Okay, so I have a GameField class, and a GameObject class and a Panel class.
The GameObject class describes an object, which has an x and y position, width and height, and x and y direction (in which it is currently moving). The GameField class has a few different instances of these objects, some stored by themselves, and some stored in primitive arrays.

The Panel class is supposed to display these objects on the screen. I used JPanel for this.
However, when it comes to actually displaying them on the screen, I'm a bit lost. I need to implement a function called paintComponent(Graphics graphics), which takes in a Graphics object.

To start, I want to display all the objects on the screen, and set their colour. Their size, position, etc. are handled elsewhere. How can I use these attributes to set the actual objects to have a size, position and direction?

I may need to override the paintComponent function to display all the objects in GameField.

If you could help me out with some code, that'd be great.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite clear on what you mean by "their size, position, etc. are handled elsewhere". For now, let's assume that you have approximately the following structure (fields and other methods ommitted for clarity) :

```
class GameObject {

     java.awt.Color     getColor() { ... }
     java.awt.Point     getPosition() { ... }
     java.awt.Point     getDirection() { ... }
     java.awt.Dimension getSize { ... }
} 

class GameField {

     List<GameObject> getGameObjects() { ... }
}

class Panel extends JPanel {

    private GameField getGameField() { ... }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // this is where the GameObjects must be painted
    }
}
```

The paintComponent method is responsible for the screen representation of the Panel class. If you override it, you have just won that responsibility from it. Luckily, drawing is - if tedious - rather simple. You asked about that Graphics parameter. Very simply put, it is set for you by the magic of Java and gives you a toolbox to use for drawing.

First, you will want to have a clean slate whenever the panel is repainted. You cannot delete anything once it is painted, but you can easily paint the entire panel in a background color of your choice.

```
g.setColor(Color.white); // everything that is now painted will be white
g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight()); // fills the entire area with the set color
```

Now, for each GameObject you have, let's place rectangle in the objects' defined color and size on the screen, with it's center on the object's position.

```
for (GameObject object : getGameField().getGameObjects()) {
    g.setColor(object.getColor());
    g.fillRect(object.getPosition().x - (object.getSize().x / 2), object.getPosition().y - object.getSize().y / 2, object.getSize().x, object.getSize().y);
}
```

The fillRect method requires the first two arguments to be the top-left corner of the rectangle. So to have it centered on the object's position, we subtract half the size from the position for the x and y values respectively. Now you have, for every GameObject, a rectangle of the right diameter in the object's color at the right position.

You should read up on the javadoc on [java.awt.Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) to find out how to draw other stuff, maybe image sprites or lines for the direction or something. It is cumbersome but doable.

Comment: Of course, you also need some mechanism to trigger the repaints on the panel.